# Including reference links in markdown as bullet point list on GitHub

Tags: github, markdown

Currently I'm using this markdown text inside the README.md file of a project on GitHub:

```
See the docs of [testthat][3] on how to write unit tests.

Links
-----

- http://www.rstudio.com/products/rpackages/devtools/
- https://github.com/hadley/testthat
- http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html

---

[1]: http://www.rstudio.com/products/rpackages/devtools/
[2]: https://github.com/hadley/testthat
[3]: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html
```

I don't like this duplication, but I don't see what choice I have. If I remove the explicit bullet point lists, then GitHub won't display the reference links. If I remove the reference links, then GitHub shows the bullet point list (of course), but the embedded links like "testthat" above don't work.

Is there a better way than duplicating? What am I missing?

Answer (score 25):

Inspired by [@mb21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214446/mb21), I suppose this would be the *right way* to do it:

```
See the docs of [testthat][2] on how to write unit tests.

Links
-----

- [RStudio Devtools][1]
- [testthat][2]
- [More unit test examples][3]

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/214446/mb21
[2]: https://github.com/hadley/testthat
[3]: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html
```

That is, it's not a good practice to include links verbatim and without a meaningful title. I should keep the link URLs only in the reference links section at the bottom, and in the bullet point list use meaningful titles.

When you view this on GitHub, the URLs shouldn't really matter, and if you really want to know you can move the mouse over. When you view this in plain text, now the links have meaningful titles, which is useful additional information about the URLs.

Answer (score 13):

I'd write that as follows:

```
See the docs of [testthat][1] on how to write unit tests.

Links
-----

- [RStudio Devtools](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rpackages/devtools/)
- [Testthat](https://github.com/hadley/testthat)
- [Tests][1]

[1]: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html
```

Did that answer your question? If not, you'll have to clarify it.

Answer (score 3):

An answer from 8 years in the future!

The answer to your question will depend on what your Markdown parser supports. Nowadays, most parsers support CommonMark (plus some flavouring). However, don't take this for granted and double check it. If CommonMark is not supported, try using the "vanilla" Markdown syntax as described below. Just be aware that the "vanilla" Markdown specification is flawed and may result in broken links (by design, almost).

### Using CommonMark

If you can guarantee that your Markdown parser supports [CommonMark](https://spec.commonmark.org/), then you can do it in a simple way:

```
Writing unit tests is explained in the [Unit Testing] website

[Unit Testing]: https://unittesting.somedomain.com
```

In the [Links](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#links) section of the CommonMark specification (currently at version 0.30) you see that a "link" is composed of a [link text](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#link-text), [link destination](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#link-destination) and a [title](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#link-title) and each one has its own syntax and quirks. For example, if the link destination contains spaces, you need to wrap it in `<angled brackets>`, or if your link text is some kind of code, you're allowed to write

```
[`AwesomeClass`](<../docs/awesome class.md>]
```

> **Note**:
>
> In *this* section I am using the CommonMark syntax, so you can click the
> "Edit" button to see the syntax that I used for a "real" example.

### Using vanilla Markdown

The vanilla [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown) specification simply requires an extra set of angled brackets with nothing in between, as described in the [links](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) section.

```
Writing unit tests is explained in the [Unit Testing][] website

[Unit Testing]: https://unittesting.somedomain.com
```

> **Note**
>
> And in *this* section I've only used vanilla Markdown syntax. Stack Overflow's Markdown parser supports both CommonMark and vanilla Markdown. This is not by accident, since CommonMark intends to be compatible with the original specification ([wherever possible!](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/apiary/faq/commonmark/index.html)). Stack Overflow do state that they use the CommonMark spec in their [Markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

### Tl;dr

```
See the docs of [`testthat`] on how to write unit tests.

Links
-----

- [RT Studio dev tools]
- [`testthat`]
- [R Packages]

---

[RT Studio dev tools]: http://www.rstudio.com/products/rpackages/devtools/
[`testthat`]: https://github.com/hadley/testthat
[R Packages]: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html
```